# Correct way to retrieve published Azure DevOps artifact

Tags: azure-devops

I am trying to set up a CI/CD pipeline for an Angular app.
I have took inspiration from a tutorial (shame on me I closed the browser tab and forgot to put a kudo-comment in the code) but eventually arranged to do this:

```
# Node.js with Angular
# Build a Node.js project that uses Angular.
# Add steps that analyze code, save build artifacts, deploy, and more:
# https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/javascript


variables:
  # Azure Resource Manager connection created during pipeline creation
  azureSubscription: 'xxx'

  # Environment name
  environmentName: 'xxx'

  # Web app name
  webAppName: 'xxx'

stages:
  - stage: Build
    displayName: Build stage
    jobs:
      - job: BuildJob
        pool:
          vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
        steps:
          - task: NodeTool@0
            inputs:
              versionSpec: '14.x'
            displayName: 'Install Node.js'
          - task: Npm@1
            inputs:
              command: 'ci'
            displayName: 'NPM CI'
          - task: Npm@1
            inputs:
              command: 'custom'
              customCommand: 'install -g @angular/cli'
            displayName: 'Install Angular'

          - script: ng build --prod
            displayName: 'build Angular'
          - task: ArchiveFiles@2
            displayName: 'Archive files'
            inputs:
              rootFolderOrFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/dist/App-FE'
              includeRootFolder: false
              archiveType: zip
              archiveFile: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
              replaceExistingArchive: true

          - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
            displayName: "Upload Artifacts"
            inputs:
              PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
              ArtifactName: 'APP-FE'
              publishLocation: 'Container'

  - stage: Deploy
    displayName: 'Deploy Web App'
    dependsOn: Build
    condition: succeeded()
    jobs:
      - deployment: DeploymentJob
        pool:
          vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
        environment: $(environmentName)
        strategy:
          runOnce:
            deploy:
              steps:
                - task: AzureWebApp@1
                  displayName: 'Deploy Azure Web App : $(webAppName)'
                  inputs:
                    azureSubscription: $(azureSubscription)
                    appName: $(webAppName)
                    appType: webAppLinux
                    package: $(Pipeline.Workspace)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
```

The problem happens on the deploy stage.

Ideally, I have created a zip artifact to work with

```
2021-03-04T16:48:35.1679914Z File upload succeed.
2021-03-04T16:48:35.1680158Z Upload '/home/vsts/work/1/a/4406.zip' to file container: '#/7437349/APP-FE'
```

Then, the artifact is retrieved in the deploy stage

```
2021-03-04T16:48:56.3711666Z Downloading items from container resource #/7437349/APP-FE
2021-03-04T16:48:56.3712634Z Downloading artifact APP-FE from: https://dev.azure.com/xxx//_apis/resources/Containers/7437349?itemPath=APP-FE&isShallow=true&api-version=4.1-preview.4
2021-03-04T16:48:56.3725395Z Downloading APP-FE/4406.zip to /home/vsts/work/1/APP-FE/4406.zip
2021-03-04T16:48:56.3726090Z Downloaded APP-FE/4406.zip to /home/vsts/work/1/APP-FE/4406.zip
```

But this downloads a file in `/home/vsts/work/1/APP-FE/` which matches `ArtifactName`. The next job fails

```
2021-03-04T16:48:57.8428994Z ##[error]Error: No package found with specified pattern: /home/vsts/work/1/4406.zip<br/>Check if the package mentioned in the task is published as an artifact in the build or a previous stage and downloaded in the current job.
```

The correct path should be `/home/vsts/work/1/APP-FE/4406.zip`. I *may* hardcode the `$(Pipeline.Workspace)/APP-FE/$(Build.BuildId).zip` path, and in fact I did as an attempt, but I'd like to understand better what the correct syntax should be to reference the newly uploaded artifact.

Note that if I change the pipeline by hardcoding the path I fix this error and get to the next error.

The question is about **understanding** how to build a clean simple and correct pipeline

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The artifact name will always be a part of the path, as it's conceivable that the build(s) that precede this deployment may publish more than one artifact.

So, your deployment job will need to provide the artifact path, but you could try this - in your variables section:

```yaml
variables:
  ...
  artifactName: 'APP-FE'
```

then in your publish phase:

```yaml
          - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
            displayName: "Upload Artifacts"
            inputs:
              PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
              ArtifactName: $(artifactName)
              publishLocation: 'Container'
```

and then in your deployment phase:

```yaml
                - task: AzureWebApp@1
                  displayName: 'Deploy Azure Web App : $(webAppName)'
                  inputs:
                    azureSubscription: $(azureSubscription)
                    appName: $(webAppName)
                    appType: webAppLinux
                    package: $(Pipeline.Workspace)/$(artifactName)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
```

Answer (score 0):

When using the [Download Build Artifacts task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/download-build-artifacts?view=azure-devops) to download an artifact with the specified artifact name, as **@WaitingForGuacamole** mentioned, the downloaded build artifact will preserve the artifact name as the parent folder. So, in your case, the path of the downloaded artifact file should be "**$(Pipeline.Workspace)/APP-FE/$(Build.BuildId).zip**".

If you do not want the artifact name is preserved as the parent folder, you can try  using the [Download Pipeline Artifacts task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/download-pipeline-artifact?view=azure-devops). When you use this task to download a single artifact, the artifact name will not be preserved as the parent folder.