# Azure build pipeline and release pipeline nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, azure-pipelines, devops

I have a azure build pipeline and release pipeline. I am facing issue in the Publish Build Artifact. in the build pipeline the publish build artifact are creating properly in the default "drop" directory.

When I download that artifact in the release pipeline the publish file are downloading in the `home/wwwroot/apservicename/drop` on which the service are throwing error

> You do not have permission to view this directory or page.

It means my publish artifact are not downloading in the "home/wwwroot" directory.

build pipeline

```
   # Node.js
   # Build a general Node.js project with npm.
   # Add steps that analyze code, save build artifacts, deploy, and more:
   # https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/javascript
   
   trigger:
   - main
   
   pool:
     vmImage": ubuntu-latest
   
   steps:
   - task: NodeTool@0
     inputs:
       versionSpec: '12.x'
     displayName: 'Install Node.js'
   
   - script: |
       npm install
     displayName: 'npm install and build'
   
   - task: ArchiveFiles@2
     inputs:
       rootFolderOrFile: '$(Build.BinariesDirectory)'
       includeRootFolder: true
       archiveType: 'zip'
       archiveFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
       replaceExistingArchive: true
   - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
     inputs
       PathtoPublish: "."
       publishLocation: Container"
```

release pipeline

```
   steps:
   - task: DownloadBuildArtifacts@0
     displayName: 'Download Build Artifacts'
     inputs:
       "buildType": specific
       project: 'f736e2aa-631d-4bc0-a468-f8c8d1b3713a'
       "pipeline": 15
       "downloadType": specific
       "downloadPath": .
       "extractTars": false
```

What I am missing?

Comment: Could you add in a little more details about the setup? If that is the entire release pipeline, then is the agent running on a server that is hosting the application?

Comment: @nimatt what information you need more in detail, should I share screenshots?

Comment: @nimatt 
You do not have permission to view this directory or page. This message I am getting every time when I do deployment, This why I know my file are not placing in wwwrootd.

Comment: @nimatt my artifacts are downloading in wwwroot/myproject/drop, while It should be download in wwwroot directory

Comment: Why is your  `downloadPath` just `.` and not the directory you want to download them into?

Answer (score 0):

The artifact name will always be a part of the path, as it's conceivable that the build(s) that precede this deployment may publish more than one artifact.

So, your deployment job will need to provide the artifact path, but you could try this - in your variables section:

variables:
...
artifactName: 'APP-FE'
then in your publish phase:

```
      - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
        displayName: "Upload Artifacts"
        inputs:
          PathtoPublish: 
     '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
          ArtifactName: $(artifactName)
          publishLocation: 'Container'
```

Comment: Please follow this link. 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66479749/correct-way-to-retrieve-published-azure-devops-artifact